# Preventing double click on google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

When I make double click the form submitted twice. It creates duplicated rows. How can I prevent double click ?

Thank you!

```
function doGet(e) {
  //Logger.log( Utilities.jsonStringify(e) );
  if (!e.parameter.page) {
    // When no specific page requested, return "home page"
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('employee').evaluate()
    .setTitle('care backup').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  }
  // else, use page parameter to pick an html file from the script
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page']).evaluate()
  .setTitle('care').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but just an option- also Set a time based trigger to run function reset every so often?

```js
var recentSubmit = 0;

function doGet(e) {
  //Logger.log( Utilities.jsonStringify(e) );
if (recentSubmit = 0){  
  if (!e.parameter.page) {
    var recentSubmit = 1;
    // When no specific page requested, return "home page"
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('employee').evaluate()
    .setTitle('care backup').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  }
  // else, use page parameter to pick an html file from the script
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page']).evaluate()
  .setTitle('care').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  }
  Logger.log("Submitted a form to recently, try again later...");
}

function reset() {
var recentSubmit = 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [createClientHandler.forEventSource().setEnabled(false)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/client-handler#foreventsource). It can disable the submit button. It's deprecated but it still works for now.

Full code implementation sample is found in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549499/how-to-disable-a-button-when-clicked):

```
function onOpen() {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle('My Title');
  app.setHeight(150);
  app.setWidth(300);

  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel();

  flow.add(app.createHidden("action", 'action'));
  flow.add(app.createLabel('My Label'));

  //Submit
  var submit = app.createButton('Run', app.createServerHandler('notif').addCallbackElement(form)).setId('run');
  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().setEnabled().setEnabled(false);
  submit.addClickHandler(cliHandler);
  flow.add(submit);

  form.add(flow);
  app.add(form);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);

};

function notif(){  
  //DO NOTHING. JUST SHOW THE button is DISABLED.
}
```

button is greyed-out after clicking..

[image]

Comment: I don't want the button to be disable. I just want not to have double click and how can I support this on HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile?